# SPFx - Webparts won't load proper on first load

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spfx, spfx-webparts

I'm currently making SPFx Webparts for the SharePoint Online segment.
Since some time when I start a new browser session and head over to my 'portal' 1 of duplicates partially to other components. See below pictures:

**Picture 1** - On first load of new session in browser
[image: On first load of new session in browser]

**Picture 2**: After reload of page
[image: After reload of page]

I can't really find any solution on this. And since I'm quite new to the framework, I'm not sure what I need to look for to actually solve this issue.

Comment: Does this happen every time? or is there any way you can try to find the pattern? Then, what kind of web part you're building? a normal one, or is it an isolated web part (iframe-rendered)? React or just normal js? It'd be good also if you could just paste the code of your render function. And also, what does the console (F12) log tells you when you reload for the first time? any error message?

Comment: The pattern that I follow is opening a new (incognito) window of chrome or edge. Go directly to the URL of the board and it pops up like screenshots above. There aren't any error messages. The webpart is a 'normal' webpart, no iframes used, codewise atleast. I'm building the components in React. I can't really paste any of the code due to the fact that messages here are to long then.